# How to add custom icons to my Quicklaunch Widget in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, icons

I want to add two app shortcuts to my panel, using the quicklaunch widget. The apps' icons look like this in the file manager:

[image: apps as shown in the file manager]

When I put them in my quicklaunch, however, they look like this:

[image: apps as shown in the quicklaunch]

They are the two apps on the right. Both look the same.

How can I change their icons? I have tried to search about changing an app's icon in quicklaunch, but Icouldn't find any help.

Comment: @David When editing please also embed images to posts by using `[![image description][n]][n]`, where `n` is the number of the image's link.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I have never got that to work. I also never did any such edit in this post.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Is there someway or place to practice this?

Comment: @David Just try it on a post with images. You should be able to see if you did it correctly in the edit preview.

Comment: Thx for the edit guys

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new blank file (make sure the file name ends with `.desktop`) and edit it to include only this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Your Executable Name
Icon=/path/to/your/icon.png
Exec=/path/to/your/executable_file.sh
Terminal=false
```

Simply replace the Name, Icon, and Exec values with the relevant ones.

Then you can add the new file to your Quick Launch widget, and it will show up with the custom icon.